# Attaching a cloud disk, how to format disk if its larger than 2 TiB

Tags: alibaba-cloud-ecs

I found the device name of the disk by going to :

**ECS Console > Block Storage > Disks > (Disk ID specific) More > Modify Atrributes.**

The run

```
fdisk /dev/vdb
```

To create a new partition. But I do not think it is working for disk bigger than 2 TiB, so what is the procedure for doing the same for those.

Answer (score 0):

using parted you can create a partition larger than 2TB.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the file system directly on the disk, without a partition table:

```
# mkfs.xfs /dev/vdb
```

But GPT support was added to fdisk in util-linux in 2012, so this should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As 2TiB exceeds the limits of MBR you must use GPT partition.

Here you can find the list of the tools https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/partitioning#Partitioning_tools

You can use:

- [gdisk](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html)
- [parted](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Parted)
- [GParted](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Parted#Interactive_mode)